# Abort navigation back if unsaved changes (ios7)

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

I want to prompt the user to save changes before they navigate back out of editing an entity in my IOS7 application.

An early stack overflow said I can detect this will happen at this point here: but I've been unable to abort the navigation.

```
-(void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent {
NSLog(@"\t\t\tThis VC has has been pushed popped OR covered");

if (!parent) {
    NSLog(@"\t\t\tThis happens ONLY when it's popped");

}
```

}

basically if my `managedObjectContext` has unsaved changes I'd like to pop an alert box before the back navigation event happens.  Any ideas?

I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19210888/2069812
but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Normally, you need to intercept and check before allowing user to navigate away from any view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom back button and handle its touch event yourself. It's the simplest solution in this case.

For example:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonDidTouch:)];

- (void)buttonDidTouch:(id)sender)
{
    if (edited) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        // Do your stuffs
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details when answering a question to make it easier for the OP and future users to understand.

Comment: Sorry for that, added example

Comment: No problem. Its full authoritative answers which make this site useful. its easier for people to quickly decide if the answer is useful to them or not.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is not using `-(void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent`, but the easiest would be to just display no back button.

This can be done via:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

You can also disable the swipe gesture as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213640/1578508):

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

But if you really want to hack in there then I would try a custom back button and handle the action in the controller.

Comment: But I still need a back button... how do you suggest i go about that?

Comment: edited my answer with a try, but I'm not sure if this can work.. cause usually these delegate methods are just invoked to react to it in order to save this data for example.

Comment: I'll give that a shot... it looks like you are trying to hack the navStack and push yourself back on?

Comment: Yes, that would be my try. There is no nice API for interfering this pop back of the navigation controller

Comment: The other possibility would be setting a custom back button in the navbar. This would enable you to receive the action of the button and react like you want it to.

Comment: @lukaswelte, the only issue with hiding the back button is that the user still can swipe back to recent view controller in iOS7+.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a custom button in IB and attached to it.  Issue solved.